# Are the large moons of Jupiter, Saturn, and Neptune still cooling and does this give and indication of their age?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, solar-system, cooling

The core temperatures and the rate at which they emanate heat should correspond to their estimated age. Other forces may create some heat such as the tidal locking that is supposed to be the source of heat for the water thought to be under Europa's surface. Surely significant heat loss from the core cannot continue indefinitely.

Comment: This question might (or might not) be more likely to get a good answer at earth science stack exchange. (It's on topic here as well though.)

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed give indication of their ages, by knowing their cooling rate and estimating their temperatures at formation we can estimate the time since this formation... Not sure if that's what you were looking for.